# Delete EncryptedSharedPreferences with clear() not working

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, androidx

I use the EncryptedSharedPreferences from the androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-alpha02 lib to store some Tokens. If i use `prefs.edit().remove("token")).apply()` or `prefs.edit().remove("token")).commit()` the token is removed. But if i try to clear the prefs at once with the `clear()` method nothing happens.

This call: `prefs.edit().clear().commit()` even returns `false`.

I get the EncryptedSharedPreferences by using this method:

```
    private fun getPrefs(): SharedPreferences {

    val masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)
    return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
            "myPrefs",
            masterKeyAlias,
            context,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM

    )
}
```

Do i have to clear the EncryptedSharedPreferences in some other way?

The documentation says
(https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) :

> // use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

**Update 07.02.2020** 
I created a bug ticket in the google bugtracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138314232) but they wont fix it...

Comment: The `EncrypedSharedPreferences` is a new api, it might be a bug. Check out the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=EncryptedSharedPreferences if there is no bug, then create a ticket for it.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous i found nothing and created a new Ticket. Thanks for the Link.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue. Getting the exception, java.lang.SecurityException: Could not decrypt key. decryption failed

Comment: @Tony updated the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue fixed from version **1.0.0-rc03**. Clear is working fine now. Enjoy!

Refer release note:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#security-crypto-1.0.0-rc03

Answer (score 0):

Update: as Jeevanandham indicated, this issue has been fixed.
There is now a stable version. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#version_100_3

---

Original answer:

One solution is to clear prefs using the standard, non secure preference manager.

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply();`

This will clear all the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

**Works in different activity as well!**

```
SharedPreference preference

...

preference.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",0).edit().clear().apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is bug from the library. It can not clear all the keys at once. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#security-crypto-1.0.0-rc03

So simple solution would be just to call the shared preference without encrypted instance.

```
private fun clearPref() {
       context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
           Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha01` library.

I was getting the following exception when i call `sharedPref.edit().clear().apply()`

```
Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Could not decrypt key. decryption failed
  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.decryptKey (EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:609).
```

I was not able to find any particular issue because this error is not coming on every device. So, to handle this, i  had to write custom logic to set the each key to a default value whenever i want to clear the data.

Answer (score -4):

**Use Remove method for now :**

```
public void clear(){
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 Map<String, ?> allEntr = prefs.getAll();
        for (String entry : allEntr.keySet()) {
            editor.remove(entry);
        }
        prefs.editor.clear();
        prefs.editor.apply();
 }
```